# "Sync flush" for Zlib Deflate

Tags: c#, zlib, flush, deflate, deflatestream

I need a zlib deflate compressed stream. In my implementation I must use a single stream over the entire session. during this session small chunks of data will be passed through the compressed stream. Everytime a chunk is passed it must be sent in compressed form immediately.

My first attempt was using DeflateStream but when I send the first chunk its compressed data wont appear until I close the stream.

Reading about [zlib flush modes](http://www.bolet.org/~pornin/deflate-flush.html) it appears as if there is one specific mode for what I need.

1. Am I using the correct class(DeflateStream) for zlib deflate compression?
2. How can I enable "sync flush" behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) project has a submodule Zlib that contain an implementation of DeflateStream of its own.

This implementation has another property named FlushMode:

```
DeflateStream deflate = new DeflateStream(stream, CompressionMode.Compress);
deflate.FlushMode = FlushType.Sync;
deflate.Write (data, 0, data.Length);
//No call to deflate.Flush() needed, automatically flushed on every write.
```

Comment: Unfortunately this library doesn't support async methods properly. Although compression itself doesn't benefit from async operations (it's CPU bound) the underlying stream often does benefit if you are sending/receiving through a network.

Answer (score 0):

It does indeed only flush upon close. You will need to use a different DeflateStream instance each time, passing **true** to the [overloaded constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bc2dbwea.aspx) telling it **not** to close the *underlying* stream when you close the DeflateStream.

Comment: I'm afraid that is not an option since the stream starts with a predefeined initiation chunk of 900 bytes, hence my requirement of a single running stream.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question about how you could enable "sync flush" behavior, you should see the zpipe.c example in the zlib source code.
Replace the 1st line with the 2nd line shown below

`Deflate()` will return each time the output buffer is full 
or when the input buffer is empty meanwhile appending to the 
compressed stream an empty literal block also called a 
"sync flush" except at the end which is the `Z_FINISH` flag.

```
    flush = feof(source) ? Z_FINISH : Z_NO_FLUSH;
    flush = feof(source) ? Z_FINISH : Z_SYNC_FLUSH;
    ret = deflate(&strm, flush);
```